# How to open a fragment by string name?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to open a random fragment. Now I open it generating a random number and with a switch, case 1, case2, etc., I open fragment 1, 2, etc. These fragments are levels and their names are: Nivel1, Nivel2, etc.

But I want to do more than 100 levels and it's a lot of code if I use this method. Is there any way to generate the random number and then if the number is 2 show Nivel2() fragment, etc?

This is my actual code:

```
public class Xtreme extends Activity {
String SiguienteNivel;
static int randomFragmentNum;
static int NivelesTotales=30;
static Random random = new Random();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_xtreme);
    randomFragmentNum = random.nextInt(7);
    Fragment();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.xtreme, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void Fragment() {
    switch (randomFragmentNum) {
        case 0: {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Nivel1()).commit();
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Nivel2()).commit();
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Nivel3()).commit();
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Nivel4()).commit();
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Nivel5()).commit();
            break;
        }
        case 5: {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Nivel6()).commit();
            break;
        }
        case 6: {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Nivel7()).commit();
            break;
        }
        case 7: {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Nivel8()).commit();
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a class by its name:

```
try{
    Fragment f = (Fragment)(Class.forName("com.example.Fragment"+i).newInstance());
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,f).commit();
}catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
    Log.e("loading level","level class not found",e);
}
```

Comment: And in "i" what i need to put?

Comment: I tried this but doesn't work:

private String i=String.valueOf(randomFragmentNum);
    Fragment Frag=(Fragment)Class.forName("com.example.Fragment"+i).newInstance();

Comment: You have to handle the exception. This is pretty common when juggling classes like this. Wrap this part of code in try - catch block.

Comment: I used your new answer but now I open the activity but the container stays white and nothing shows i edited the code to open for example Level 7 but i have the same result

Answer (score 1):

Zielony answer is good for solving this particular issue, but as advice I would like to add. I don't know how creating a fragment class file for each level is a good approach to this. Even more if you want to create 100 plus levels. Look for a way to make the levels dynamic. If you can't, are you really sure you will want to have the work to create 100 levels? Or at least do the xml layouts and see if all levels have the same gameplay. If so, then you can just do the random, get the level layout name and pass it to the fragment for it to be recreated with the new layout.

Comment: This is true. I don't see any way you may need 100 different classes for your levels

Comment: Because all the levels are diferent and have diferent "minigame" por example level 1 you have to answer a question with numbers, level 2 you have 1 second to click a button, etc. I have to do a big work!

sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: I see, 100 unique levels is a lot of work. Well, good luck with that. Still, look for similarities between levels and see if you can separate levels into categories of levels, like levels with some number of seconds to click button.